# macOS different Prompt meaning `%` vs `$`

Tags: linux, permissions, macos-catalina

when I open the terminal on my MacBook(macOS Catalina 10.15.7) I got this:`myMacBook-Pro:~ foo$` Prompt behind my username is `$`; And when I open the iMac(macOS Catalina 10.15.7) where I work, I got this: `foo@myImac ~ %`, the prompt is `%`. Why prompt is different, cause of the different machine type(desktop vs laptop)? or the user permission(both of them I logged in with admin account)?

Comment: macOS has recently switched from Bash to ZSH as the default shell due to licensing issues with Bash but since you use the same OS on both machines it might be something different (it's also possible that an upgrade removed Bash and replaced it with ZSH). Post output of `echo $PS1` on both machines.

Comment: Hi @ArkadiuszDrabczyk , the output of `echo $PS1` for MacBook is `\h:\W \u\$`, so that means for user prompt is `$`; for iMac is `%n@%m %1~ %#`;

Answer (score 3):

% is for zsh which is a Unix shell that is built on top of bash (the default shell for macOS) with additional features. It's recommended to use zsh over bash. So, zsh (Z shell) is the default shell for all newly created user accounts, starting with macOS Catalina.