# Prompt line ends with ~% rather than a ~$

Tags: terminal

My macOS Catalina version 10.15.7  TERMINAL has the following prompt line.  Why does it end in a ~% rather than a ~$ as shown in the examples below:
My terminal looks like this:
MACK@Williams-MacBook-Pro ~%

and I think it should look like this:
Percys-Macbook-Pro~ toptechskills$

OR is it OK that I have a ~% at the end.  Seems to be working with %, but not sure if it should have $ instead.

Comment: `OR is it OK that I have a ~% at the end. Seems to be working with %, but not sure if it should have $ instead.` Of course it is working. Why wouldn't it, its "just" a prompt.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but it's possible it has to do with the [changeover](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/) from `bash` to `zsh`?

Comment: This is a duplicate post, @stealthyyoda, please go to this post to find the answer you seek.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405994/macos-different-prompt-meaning-vs

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found my answer and more with the following video by Corey Schafer on how to customize your terminal - 17 minutes long and went into great detail on how to customize the prompt line, colors and content, etc.

Terminal > Customizing your Prompt
https://youtu.be/LXgXV7YmSiU

AND this video provides more background for the above video - both very good:
Customizing Your Terminal: .bash_profile and .bashrc files:
https://youtu.be/vDOVEDl2z84

Thanks to the others that provided input.
Stealthyoda out